# Linux SUID permission bit behavior - what am I missing?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

Suppose the following directory structure:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root       script
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root       owned_by_root
```

Suppose also that `script` is a simple shell script with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo "Appending $2 to $1..."
echo -n "$2" >> $1
```

and that `owned_by_root` is an empty file.

---

As `owned_by_root` is clearly owned by the `root` user, and as the write flag is set only for the owning user, the following obviously fails when executed under a non-root account:

```
user@machine 
$ ./script ./owned_by_root "Hi"
```

Now, if I set the SUID bit of the `script` file, like so:

```
sudo chmod u+s ./script
```

(resulting in the permissions bits of `script` being `-rwsr-xr-x`), to my surprise,

```
user@machine 
$ ./script ./owned_by_root "Hi"
```

still fails, with `./script: line 4: owned_by_root: Permission denied`.

It was my impression that setting the SUID bit on the script executable would lead to any 3rd party user account being able to append to `./owned_by_root`.

SUID is usually explained by the `/etc/passwd`/`/usr/bin/passwd` dynamic, whose permission bits match those of `owned_by_root` and `script`, respectively. There must be something I'm missing/misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Linux ignores the SETUID bit on shebang (`#!`) scripts. This can be confirmed by adding a `sleep` command to the script and inspecting the process table in the meantime:

```
$ ps aux | grep -i script

user   1271826  0.0  0.0  10084  2796 pts/4    S+   18:20   0:00 /usr/bin/bash ./script owned_by_root Hello
```

By observing the first column it is apparent that the `bash` process is running under the same user who initially executed the script.

The same is not true for compiled programs, which `/usr/bin/passwd` is.